# Como usar variável no sort JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, classificação

estou fazendo uma ordenação em javascript a partir do método sort, mas gostaria de saber se é possível usar uma variável para representar o atributo que será usado para a ordenação já que esse atributo pode variar.

O código ficou assim:

```
msg.produtos.sort(function(a, b){

    if( a.valorProduto < b.valorProduto){
        return -1;
    }else if (a.valorProduto > b.valorProduto ){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;    
});
return msg;
```

Eu imaginei algo assim:

```
let criterio;

criterio = msg.exemplo.criterio;//(supondo que o valor do atributo criterio fosse valorProduto).
msg.produtos.sort(function(a, b){

    if( a.criterio < b.criterio){
        return -1;
    }else if (a.criterio > b.criterio){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;    
});
return msg;
```

Porém não deu certo porque ele tenta achar um atributo com o nome "critério" e não um atributo com o valor dentro de critério.

OBS: 
`produto` é um array de objetos com os mesmos atributos;
O atributo que será usado como critério irá variar e será definido em um momento anterior.

Existe alguma forma de fazer ele usar o valor dentro da variável critério ou teria que fazer um `if( criterio === x)` e para cada caso montar um sort com o atributo em questão?

Comment: Não seria esse o caso de utilizar `a[criterio]  < b[criterio]`? Assim você pode acessar a propriedade com o mesmo nome do valor que existir na variável `criterio`.

Comment: Fiz o teste, mas apresenta o seguinte erro: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token [".
É nodered

Comment: Essa sintaxe é válida, não deveria dar erro de token inesperado. Você não colocou um ponto ou algo do tipo antes do colchete, colocou?

Comment: Deu certo!!!
Não tirei o . antes do colchetes por isso não tinha dado certo.

Comment: @user140828 dá uma resposta para a pergunta ficar com resposta

Answer (score 0):

A dúvida foi solucionado conforme os comentários.

Solução: usar a variável dentro de **[]** e sem o "**.**", ficando:

```
let criterio;

criterio = msg.exemplo.criterio;//(supondo que o valor do atributo criterio fosse valorProduto).
msg.produtos.sort(function(a, b){

if( a[criterio] < b[criterio]){
    return -1;
}else if (a[criterio] > b[criterio]){
    return 1;
}
return 0;    
});
return msg;
```